# Best database schema for country, region, county, town

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have country, region, county, town data and I'm currently deciding between 2 schema designs (if there's a better one, do tell).

I first thought

- Country

  - Id
  - Name
- Region

  - Id
  - CountryId
  - Name
- County

  - Id
  - RegionId
  - Name
- Town

  - Id
  - CountyId
  - Name

Does the job however to get all towns in a country you have to 3 inner joins to do the filtering.  I guess this could be ok but potentially expensive?

The other design was:

- Country

  - Id
  - Name
- Region

  - Id
  - Name
- County

  - Id
  - Name
- Town

  - Id
  - CountryId
  - RegionId
  - CountyId
  - Name

This way all hierarchical data so to speak is at the bottom and you can go back up however if you want all regions in a country you're a bit screwed which makes we wonder whether the first design is best.

What do you think is the best schema design?

Comment: Why not: Geography{TownName, CountyName, RegionName, CountryName}? All four attributes are key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best database design depends on how the data is being used.

If this is pretty static data that will all be updated at one time and external references are all to towns, then I would probably go for a denormalized dimension.  That is, store the information all in one row:

- Town Id
- Town name
- County name
- Region name
- Country name

Under the above scenario, the ids for county, region, and country are not necessary (by assumption).

If the data is being provided as separate tables with separate ids, and these tables can be updated independently or row-by-row, then a separate table for each makes sense.  Putting all the ids into the `towns` table may or may not be a good idea.  You will have to verify and maintain the hierarchies when data is inserted and updated.

If ids for each level are necessary for your, then you should have appropriate table structure for declaring foreign key constraints.  But, this can get complicated.  Will an external entity have a "geography" attribute that can be at any level?  Will an external always know what level it is going to refer to as?

In other words, you need to know how the data is going to be used in order to define an appropriate data model.